# How to build multiple projects from same solution with .bat script?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, batch-file

i need to build three projects from same solution.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwTPI.png)

Above image shows the current solution. I want to build only 3 three of them; mainly .Web(ASP.NET), .Server(C# Console), Client.Browser(Winforms).

I want to build them by creating a XML script. We have found this on Stackoverflow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputDir>C:\TESTMSBUILDOUTPUT</OutputDir>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectToBuild Include="XXXXbook2.sln" >
        <Properties>OutputPath=$(OutputDir);Configuration=MSBuildRelease;Platform=x86</Properties>
    </ProjectToBuild>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(AllFiles)"/>
</Target>
```

This is for building for the whole projects inside solution. But we want to specify only three of them. What is the right format for this? Is there any tools to generate such a script.

Thanks in advance.